# Set of a Property is not being fired when ValidationRule returns false

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, validation

I have a ValidationRule on a Text Box.  When the ValidationResult returns true, this fires the set on the property that the text box is bound to.

When the ValidationResult returns false, the set is not fired.

Any pointers as to why its not firing, and how to solve it, greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Joe

Here is the XAML of the Text Box :

```
<Binding Path="CorrectEntry" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  NotifyOnValidationError="True" >
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <localValidation:CorrectEntryValidationRule x:Name="validator" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">                                                   <localValidation:CorrectEntryValidationRule.RangeContainer>
                <localValidation:CorrectEntryRangeContainer
                    DataContext="{Binding 
                    Source={StaticResource DataContextBridge}, 
                    Path=DataContext}" 
                    Min="{Binding Lower}"
                    Max="{Binding Upper}"
                    />
                </localValidation:CorrectEntryValidationRule.RangeContainer>
            </localValidation:CorrectEntryValidationRule>
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for Validation Rule.  it is by design that the property don't get set when Validation Rule returns false.

You should not use Validation Rule, if you want your Propery to be set.  You should inherit your class from IDataErrorInfo.  And implement the 2 methods from that interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal and usually wanted behavior, if your data is invalid you don't want it to be saved in your model.

(If you want to do validation via exceptions thrown in the setter you can use [a property on the binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions.aspx))

Comment: Thanks H.B, I need the Set on the property to fire because this contains OnPropertyChanged...  On my form I have an Ok button which is bound to an IsValid flag, and this should be disabled - when my TextBox has an invalid entry.... this would normally be straightforward but I'm binding the values in the DataContext using Josh Smith's method : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachingVirtualBranches.aspx?df=100&forumid=415065&exp=0&select=2110158

Comment: Using a flag for this may not be such a good idea if you also use ValidationRules; i would probably use a multibinding on the IsEnabled property which binds directly to the validation status of all the controls in this case.